# Android path arc bounds

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I need to calculate arc's bounds. Sometimes, bounds look correct:

[image]

But sometimes they clearly don't:

[image]

Here is my code I used for demonstration
(if you not familiar with method signatures its just a fancy kotlin wrappers from Jetpack Compose, i hope you won't miss the point)

(for the second image i just changed start/sweep to 120f/120f):

```
Path().apply {
                this.addArc(
                    Rect(Offset.Zero, size/2f),
                    startAngleDegrees = 180f,
                    sweepAngleDegrees = 180f
                )    

                val bounds = getBounds()

                drawPath(
                    path = this,
                    brush = brush,
                    style = Stroke(pathEffect = pathEffect, width = width.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round)
                )
                drawRect(
                    brush = brush, bounds.topLeft, bounds.size,
                    style = Stroke(pathEffect = pathEffect, width = width.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round)
                )
            }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the two-argument constructor for _RectF_ used in `addArc()` (`Rect(Offset.Zero, size/2f)`). Do you have a reference for this? Is it your own or from a library?

Comment: I didn't mention that this is jetpack compose, my bad

Answer (score 0):

I found out that problem is in lack of method that calculates tight bounds e.g. bounds that doesn't count anything except points of path itself.

Problem can be solved by use of class PathMeasure

```
fun tightMeasurePath(path: Path, accuracy: Int): androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Rect {
    //Idea is to find absolute minimum and maximum coordinates of points
    //which represents bounds of path. In order to do so we use PathMeasure class
    //Accuracy = number of parts we divide our curve on
    
    val pathMeasure = android.graphics.PathMeasure(path.asAndroidPath(), false)
    //obviously represents a point
    val cache = FloatArray(2)

    //calculates point coordinates with a given position on a curve
    //pos must be in range [0, length]

    pathMeasure.getPosTan(0f, cache, null)

    var xMin: Float = cache[0]
    var xMax: Float = xMin

    var yMin: Float = cache[1]
    var yMax: Float = yMin

    do {
        //length of current curve
        val length = pathMeasure.length

        for (i in 0..accuracy) {
            val pos = length * i / accuracy
            pathMeasure.getPosTan(pos, cache, null)
            xMin = min(xMin, cache[0])
            xMax = max(xMax, cache[0])

            yMin = min(yMin, cache[1])
            yMax = max(yMax, cache[1])
        }

    } while (pathMeasure.nextContour()) //Path may contain many curves, so we calculte min and max 
    //for all of them

    return Rect(Offset(xMin, yMin), Offset(xMax, yMax))
}
```

This is an example of rect that represent bounds calculated by method above:
[image]